# User is not allowed to execute command as another user

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: true
   become_user: root
   become_method: sudo
   gather_facts: False
   tasks:     
     - name: Root user check
       shell : export PATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.12:$PATH;export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/python/Python-2.7.12;python --version;whoami
```

Im running the above playbook on remote server from userA .

The configuration for userA on remote server is as such

userA ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:ALL

Any pointers as to what Im missing..

The error Im facing is as below

```
Sorry, user userA is not allowed to execute ‘/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ltfjopjkdxnxjqhkpmgpokjgki; /usr/bin/python /home/userA/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597841138.97-224625741903296/command.py’ as root on server
```

I have tried keeping the remote ansible files and then running the command.py from the remote server manually and it works

Comment: Does userA have the same UID on both machines?

Comment: @NasirRiley yes userA has same uid on both the machines

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: Did you really logged in manually to the machines with userA and tried to "sudo su -" to become root without password? Did that work? Is sudo installed? 
`become_method: sudo` and `become_user: root`is default, you can remove that - but it will not help here. I think, there is a problem on the server not in Ansible.